# using git over ssh programmatically in C#

Tags: windows, git, github

I need to draw source code from a GIT repository in my system.
I use C# as a backend technology and so far I have succeeded with ordinary protocols.
I'm wrapping the Git.exe to call specific git commands.
When calling Git Clone "AnyUrlRepositoryOverSSH" git.exe fails. it happens because the call 
wasn't made over ssh transmission or the ssh protocol fails to deliver my public key.
I need to call a SSH client and through that client make a call to GIt.exe . How can it be done?

Comment: Could you display %HOME% in C# command wrapper? If HOME isn't defined, ssh won't know where to kook for your public/private keys.

Comment: If you are only connecting to git repositories on GitHub, check out out [Octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net).